# Some blocks on the meta site use the color scheme used by the main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I ask a question on this meta site, or edit an existing question, I see these blocks that use the same background color used on the main site.

[image: How to Ask]
  [image: How to Format]
  [image: How to Edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix will be in the next deployment.